# Monitoring memory leaks in Kubernetes cluster using prometheus and alertmanager

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

i am looking for a way to get alerts when a pod may have memory leak. we're using prometheus and alertmanager for monitoring and i wanted to ask if anyone created such rule or if you guys have any idea how we could achieve this.

Basically i am trying to use something like the following query to track the pod memory usage `(sum by(pod, namespace) (container_memory_working_set_bytes))` however i am not sure how to add the time periods and how to track the constant increase of memory overtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this query and have it over a 30 minute period (in prom rule set for: 30m). This would fire when the rate of change of memory usage over a 5 minute interval goes over 2% of the memory limit - suggesting a memory leak. Then it has to be firing for 30m so it truly fires when there is a leak.

```
100 * sum by (namespace, pod, container) (rate(container_memory_working_set_bytes[5m])) / sum by (namespace, pod, container) (kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes) > 2
```